# How to build chromium with minimum features

Tags: browser, chromium, chromium-embedded, fedora-23

I am trying to build chromium with minimal features using Fedora 23 64bit.

I followed the link from [cef website](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) did the below steps.

1. installed depot_tools package
2. ```
   mkdir chromium
   cd chromium
   fetch --no-history --no-hooks chromium

   cd src
   gclient runhooks
   gn gen out/Default

   ninja -C out/Default chrome
   ```

---

Build success

Now, When I tried launching the chrome (`out/Default/chrome`) I get the below error:

> LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:

Also, I don't see `libcef.so` anywhere in my src folder.

Please help and guide to get a mimimal version built and running.

Comment: CEF is not a part of Chromium. In order to build CEF you should follow instructions from https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

Comment: @alexeibs .. Thanks for the info. We are able to build CEF binary successfully. However, the libcef.so file size is huge (~1.4GB), is there any way to reduce the size?

Comment: Unfortunately I used CEF under Windows only and libcef.dll is not that big - about 50Mb only. PDB file with debug symbols is 1 Gb though. May be you should change some compiler settings.

Comment: You can strip the debugging info from libcef.so or move it to it's own debug symbol only file. Google how to do this it is an important lesson to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Before "`gn gen out/Default`" you need to execute these commands to get release build:

1. `gn args out/Default`, and
2. type "`is_debug = false`" in an opened editor

After build you can then run "`cd out/Default && ninja mini_installer`" to get an installer and archive of `redistributable` files.